# What does 软文 and 小号 mean in internet slang?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, slang

Just like the title says, what does 软文 and 小号 mean in internet slang?

For example:

> 还有就是严禁那些动不动就说是**软文**或**小号**的人发言

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: 还有就是严禁那些动不动就说是软文或小号的人发言

Comment: 软文 is an implicit advertisement; 小号 on a online forum means a non-primary account of the user -- a user may have many accounts, but only one or two are most active. He uses other accounts to boost the popularity of his own posts, or to post something that he doesn't want others to find out the poster...

Comment: 小号 means alt characters in gaming. A non-primary account of forum (sockpuppet) is better called 马甲. There is slight difference. In the context you provided, 小号 means sockpuppet but I prefer to use 马甲.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the Internet, 軟文 means an article intended as advertisement but disguised as ordinary posts. 小號 means the *auxiliary accounts*, referring to the usual practice of cyber forum participants maintaining multiple accounts so that his or her posts can be *bumped* up or appeared as if well received.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't speak Chinese for long time(I am a Chinese!!) but I think 小号 means go to the toilet.

Comment: which is not common on the Internet.

Comment: thanks, I might use it someday :). Can you clarify whether 小号 is 大便 or 小便？

Comment: 小号is 小便, mind that the officially meaning of 小号is a trumpet.

Comment: @Red2awn:thanks, so 大号 means 大便 ? :D

Comment: I am not sure, but I think so. Sorry, I haven't speak Chinese for a whole year.

Comment: 最近的中文流行语中，“小号”的意思是在论坛上故意额外注册的另一个账号。最主要使用的账号叫做“大号”；不常用的那个“傀儡账号”叫做“小号”。

Comment: @Victor: 恩。。。。。

Comment: Nonsense! I have never used 小号 for 小便, obviously it is just a dialect word, and also the topic is talking about internet slang but not dialect.